# When does the long enumeration in this poem starts and ends?

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

The Busy Heart by Rupert Brooke

> Now that we've done our best and worst, and parted,
>
> I would fill my mind with thoughts that will not rend.
>
> (O heart, I do not dare go empty-hearted)
>
> I'll think of Love in books, Love without end;
>
> Women with child, content; and old men sleeping;
>
> And wet strong ploughlands, scarred for certain grain;
>
> And babes that weep, and so forget their weeping;
>
> And the young heavens, forgetful after rain;
>
> And evening hush, broken by homing wings;
>
> And Song's nobility, and Wisdom holy,
>
> That live, we dead. I would think of a thousand things,
>
> Lovely and durable, and taste them slowly,
>
> One after one, like tasting a sweet food.

When does the long enumeration in this poem starts and ends? It seems that the enumeration starts with "Love without end" and then ends with "and Wisdom holy that live, we dead" although I am not sure what "and Wisdom holy, that live, we dead". Can someone rewrite this part in simple English?

Comment: It's ambiguous - I'd suppose that "that live, we dead" is intended to modify all the items in the list (not just Song and Wisdom), but the punctuation suggests otherwise. It's possibly punctuated in an unconventional way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question of learning English.  Rather it is a question of poetry analysis.  [literature.se] might be a better home.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see mention of a 'long enumeration' in the poem.

The closest thing to that would seem to be everything after "I'll think of..." up to "... wisdom holy...", i.e. the series of items separated by "and". All those items are direct objects of "I'll think of...".

That collection of things amounts to a noun phrase. The poet is saying about those things that they live, although, or after, we are dead.

Comment: Yes - _that live_ refers to all the things he has mentioned, not just wisdom. Sayaman, note that the title is "The Busy Heart"; putting the article at the end is just for indexing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers have addressed the meaning of *that live, we dead*.

I take it to mean " ... that live (even when) we (are) dead".

"We dead" is an absolute clause. In prose it would probably read "we being dead": only in poetry can you get away with omitting the "being".